# Two separate window in LESS file

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, less, frontend

I am learning web development and in the middle of a tutorial teacher converted CSS file to LESS file and told that now if I open the LESS file in VS I will see two windows. But I do not see two window in my Visual Studio Community 2015 edition. I just see one window with the LESS file in it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: He might have dragged another tab (the compiled CSS maybe?) into another window within Visual Studio. I don't think it will do that on its own.

Comment: You might be right. But there might be some plugins such as web essentials or any other which might open the compiled CSS by default side by side to LESS file. Anyways thanks for your inputs. If I get to know one I will put it in this answer section.

Answer (score 3):

Before VS2015 Web Essentials used to compile .LESS files and open them in two separate files, now you have to use Web Compiler:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler

When you compile your .LESS file it will generate a .CSS so you can open that as well and set to "New Vertical Tab Group", and you will have side-by-side files.
Also, Web Compiler compiles on save.

Comment: This answer is still correct with VS2019. Note that there will be a right click menu available so when you first install the extension you can right-click on your new .less file and compile (create) the .css file.

Comment: For VS2022 please install this Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Failwyn.WebCompiler64, and the rest are the same as the comment above for the VS2019.